# Update Connected Database Table as Rows are Added to an ASP.NET MVC Table

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

The following code makes up parts of an ASP.NET MVC application that I am currently working on. The index creates a table that the user can add rows by inputting the values for Tag, Server, and Frequency into a popup modal (activated by hitting the "Add" button, modal HTML code not shown). The table's initial values are currently generated by a migration from a linked SQL Database Table (created by using entity-framework).

I am trying to modify this code so that any rows added by the "Add" button will be automatically added to the linked Database Table (preferably by using entity framework). Any help would be appreciated.

**Controller**

```
namespace ExampleWebAppilcationTest.Controllers
{
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    ExampleDB _db = new ExampleDB();

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = _db.TData.ToList();
        return View(model);
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (_db != null)
        {
            _db.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
}
```

**Classes**

```
namespace ExampleWebAppilcationTest
{
public class ExampleDB : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<TableData> TData { get; set; }
}
}



namespace ExampleWebAppilcationTest
{
public class TableData
{
    [Key]
    public String Tag { get; set; }
    public String Server { get; set; }
    public double Frequency { get; set; }
}
}
```

**Index**

```
@model IEnumerable<ExampleWebAppilcationTest.TableData>

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Table Data</h2>

<table class="table table-bordered" id="mainTable">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th class="thTag" scope="col">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Tag)
        </th>
        <th class="thServer" scope="col">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Server)
        </th>
        <th class="thFreq" scope="col">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Frequency)
        </th>
    </tr>
</thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="5">

                        @foreach (var item in Model)
                        {
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox"/></td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Tag)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Server)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Frequency)
                </td>
            </tr>
</tbody>
</table>

        <button type="button" id="addBtn" class="btn btn-success">Add</button>

            <!-- The Modals -->

            <script>

                var table = document.getElementById('mainTable');
                // Get the modal
                var addmodal = document.getElementById('addModal');

                // When the user clicks the button, open the modal
                btn.onclick = function () {
                    addmodal.style.display = "block";
                }

               var sbtn = document.getElementById("subBtn");
                sbtn.onclick = function () {
                    var table = document.getElementById("mainTable");
                    var tag = document.getElementById("tag").value;
                    var server = document.getElementById("server").value;
                    var frequency = document.getElementById("frequency").value;
                    var objInputCheckBox = document.createElement("input");
                    objInputCheckBox.type = "checkbox";
                    var row = table.insertRow(-1);
                    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
                    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
                    var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
                    var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
                    cell1.appendChild(objInputCheckBox);
                    cell2.innerHTML = tag;
                    cell3.innerHTML = server;
                    cell4.innerHTML = frequency;
                    addmodal.style.display = "none";

                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you should have a **Layered Architecture** for your project with separare Business and DataAccess layers and controller should only be the gateway for incoming requests https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/microservices-architecture/microservice-ddd-cqrs-patterns/infrastructure-persistence-layer-design )

This is what you can do with your current adjustment:

**Controller**:

```
namespace ExampleWebAppilcationTest.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            using (var dbContext = new ExampleDB())
            {
                var model = dbContext.TData.ToList();
                return View(model);
            }
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(TableData data)
        {
            using (var dbContext = new ExampleDB())
            {
                dbContext.TData.Add(data);
                dbContext.SaveChanges();
            }

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
    }
}
```

**Data Access**

```
namespace ExampleWebAppilcationTest
{
public class ExampleDB : DbContext
{
    public ExampleDB() : base(nameOrConnectionString: "Your Database Connection String") { }
    public DbSet<TableData> TData { get; set; }
}
}



namespace ExampleWebAppilcationTest
{
public class TableData
{
    [Key]
    public String Tag { get; set; }
    public String Server { get; set; }
    public double Frequency { get; set; }
}
}
```

**View**

```
sbtn.onclick = function () {
            var table = document.getElementById("mainTable");
            var tag = document.getElementById("tag").value;
            var server = document.getElementById("server").value;
            var frequency = document.getElementById("frequency").value;

            //Here fetch all data in a class
            var data = { Tag: tag, Server: server, Frequency: frequency };

            //make ajax call to add data
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '@Url.Action("Index", "Home")',     //your action
                data: data,
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (result) {
                    //to close the popup
                },
                error: function (result) {
                    //to show error message
                }
            });
                }
```

Comment: After these changes, the Database Table is still not showing any additional rows.

Comment: I realized the issue. In your ajax call, the url needs to be '/Home/Index', not '/Index/Home'. Thank you for your help. If you get the chance, please update your answer.

Comment: Ahh..Updated the answer using @Url.Action. Mark it as answer if found useful.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an Add method of some sort to your controller, decorated with the POST attribute. In your modal, there needs to be a form pointing to the controller's add method  url. The form should contain input fields for all of your table properties. That form should be then posted via a submit button to the add method on your controller. The add method needs to take the properties of the form submitted, create a new object, then insert the new object in to the database.